# MSSQL Count Distinct Column with Space in Name

Tags: sql-server

So I have set my query with `@query =` then later I am `exec sp_execute @query;`

I have a column with spaces in and brackets so it is `'Real (Color)'`
I have grouped the statement so I need to have a count distinct for each of the variations of `Real (Color)`.

I have tried..

`count(''distinct Real (Color)'')` - Returns count of all rows.

``` count(distinct ``Real (Color)'') ```  - Returns 1.

`count(distinct Real (Color))` - Throws syntax error.

Im wondering if this an issue if im am trying to count distinct string values?

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: What is the column Name? [Real (Color)] ?

Comment: use square bracker like this - `count(distinct [Real (Color)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
count(distinct [Real (Color)])
```

Should do the trick.